# $f([a,b])=[f(a),f(b)]$ for continuous strictly monotonic function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ is continuous and strictly monotonic function on $[a,b]$. Prove that $$f([a,b])=[f(a),f(b)].$$

**Proof:**
We know that $[a,b]$ is a connected set in $\mathbb{R}$ then $f([a,b])$ is connected since $f$ is continuous. Also $f(a),f(b)\in f([a,b])$. Hence $[f(a),f(b)]\subseteq f([a,b]).$

Let $y\in f([a,b])$ then $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in[a,b]$. Since $x\in[a,b]$ then $f(a)\leqslant y\leqslant f(b)$. Hence $f([a,b])\subseteq [f(a),f(b)]$ and thereby $f([a,b])=[f(a),f(b)]$.

Is my proof true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems fine to me :)

Comment: It is a bit of a silly corner case, but, you seem to be using that $f$ is  increasing (rather than possibly decreasing). I guess that an interval $[c,d]$ should then be defined in some way equivalent to $\{(1-t)c+td\,|\, t \in\mathbb{R}, 0\leq t\leq 1\}$ for the result be true for a decreasing function...