# Basic Properties of Paramerized curve

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\gamma_1$ be a curve in $\mathbb{R}^k$, defined on $[a,b]$; let $\phi$ be a continuous 1-1 mapping of $[c,d]$ onto $[a,b]$, such that $\phi (c)=a$; and define $\gamma_2(s)=\gamma_1(\phi(s))$. Prove that $\gamma_2$ is an arc, a closed curve, or a rectifiable curve if and only if the same is true for $\gamma_1$. Prove that $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_1$ have the same length.

It's problem 19 from Rudin's PMA.

I have the following remarks to this problem:

1) I think that condition $\phi (c)=a$ is excess. Since $\phi:[c,d]\to [a,b]$ is continuous 1-1 and onto mapping then $\phi$ is strictly monotonic function and $\phi(c)=a$ and $\phi(d)=b$ which was proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514328/fa-b-fa-fb-for-continuous-strictly-monotonic-function).

2) $\gamma_2$ is rectifiable **iff** $\gamma_1$ is rectifiable. From here we obtain that $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ have the same length. Why Rudin asks "Prove that $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_1$ have the same length"? I think that it's also extra question.

What you think about these remarks?

By the way here is my proof:

**Q1.** $\gamma_2$ is a closed curve iff $\gamma_2$ is a closed curve.

$\blacktriangleright$ $\Rightarrow$ Let $\gamma_2$ is a closed. Then $\gamma_2(c)=\gamma_1(\phi(c))=\gamma_1(a)$ and $\gamma_2(d)=\gamma_1(\phi(d))=\gamma_1(b)$. Then $\gamma_1(a)=\gamma_1(b).$ Converse claim is analogous. $\blacktriangleleft$

**Q2.** $\gamma_2$ is an arc iff $\gamma_2$ is an arc.

$\blacktriangleright$ $\Rightarrow$ Let $\gamma_2$ is an arc. If $\gamma_1(s_1)=\gamma_1(s_2)$ where $s_1, s_2\in [a,b]$. Then exists $t_1, t_2$ such that $\phi(t_i)=s_i$. Then $\gamma_1(\phi(t_1))=\gamma_1(\phi(t_2))$ $\Rightarrow$ $\gamma_2(t_1)=\gamma_2(t_2)$ $\Rightarrow$ $t_1=t_2$ $\Rightarrow$ $s_1=s_2$ $\blacktriangleleft$

**Q3.** $\gamma_2$ is rectifiable iff $\gamma_1$ is rectifiable.

$\blacktriangleright$ $\Rightarrow$ Let $\gamma_2$ is rectifiable then $\Lambda(\gamma_2)=\sup \limits_{P} \Lambda(P,\gamma_2)<\infty$ where the supremum is taken ovel all partitions of $[c,d]$. To any partition $P$ of $[c,d]$ we can associate unique partition $Q$ of $[a,b]$. Then $\sup \limits_{P} \Lambda(P,\gamma_2)=\sup \limits_{Q} \Lambda(Q,\gamma_1)<\infty$. Thus $\gamma_1$ is rectifiable. $\blacktriangleleft$

What you think about these remarks and solution?
I would be really thankful to any help!